# Relation "usermgmbd.users" does not exist

Tags: sql, laravel, postgresql, go

I'm trying to left join two different databases in Postgres. Is it possible at all?
If is it possible then how i will do it? My two DB: one is apidb and another is usermgmdb. in apidb has wallets table which has user_id.

```
SELECT *
FROM wallets AS wl 
  LEFT JOIN usermgmdb.users AS us ON us.id = wl.user_id;
```

Comment: You can't join across database in Postgres, only across schemas.